# How to highlight specific row in Excel if column value is one of a list of value in another sheet

Tags: excel

I have a column in one sheet that I want the value of it to determine the color of the row (background color). So if the value exist in another sheet's set of value it will color it green otherwise red.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `another sheet's set of value` is a single column or row named List then Conditional Formatting with green fill of the column in one sheet with a rule such as:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,List,0)))
```

in conjunction with red fill for that column should serve.